# python multiprocessing map_async does take much more time than the sequential

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want to find optimum path for the Travelling salesman problem, it works fine with the sequential algorithm but I have a problem with the parallel algorithm, for example when I run sequentially everything is ok but in parallel, it took 200x more time in 4 cores computer.

Here is my sequential code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

#Traveling Salesman Solution
#Scott Stevenson, Jack Koppenaal, John Costantino

import time, itertools, math

#Get the city file
def getFile():
    cityFile = 'in.txt'
    try:
        f = open(cityFile,'r')
        return f
    except Exception as e:
        print(cityFile + ' could not be opened: ' + str(e))

def find_max():
    file = open('in.txt','r')
    max = file.read().split()
    return max[1]

def initfiles(path):
    file = open(path, 'r')
    max = file.read().splitlines()
    file.close()
    file = open(path, 'r')
    num = file.read().split()
    file.close()
    final = list()
    final.append(str(num[0] + ' ' + num[1] + ' OK'))
    if (num[2] != 'OK'):
        print('File has been edited.')

        file_write = open(path, 'wt')

        for i in range(1, int(num[0]) + 1):
            final.append(str(i) + ' ' + str(max[i]))
        for line in range(len(final)):
            file_write.write(str(final[line]) + '\n')

        file_write.close()



#Get distance between 2 cities
#Cities stored as [ident, x, y]
def getDistance(city1, city2):
    return  math.sqrt((int(city2[1]) - int(city1[1]))**2 + (int(city2[2])-int(city1[2]))**2)

#Get the cities from a specified city file
def getCities(cityFile):
    for line in cityFile:
        try:
            #Lines split by a space char will look like:
            #[ident, x-coord, y-coord]
            ident = line.split(' ')[0]
            x = line.split(' ')[1]
            y = line.split(' ')[2].strip('\n')
            #print(x,y,ident)
            #If the ident is not an int (not a city) skip it otherwise add it
            if ident.isdigit():
                #Cities are just lists with values (almost a pseudo-class)
                city = [int(ident), int(x), int(y)]
                cities.append(city)
        except:
            #The ident was not an int so we skip (pass) it and move on to the next
            pass

#A function for bruteforcing the TSP problem based on a list of cities
def bruteForce(cities):
    global maxweight
    #Tours are also stored as pseudo-class lists
    #tour[0] is the path and tour[1] is the weight

    #Make a start tour with a weight of infinity so all other tours will be smaller
    tour = [[], float("inf")]
    permparm = []
    #In order to get all permutations we need an array containing the values 1 through n
    #These values are the idents of the cities (their 0th element) so we get and add them
    for city in cities:
        permparm.append(city[0])

    #We now generate all permutations of n length from the array containing 1 - n idents
    #and loop through them looking for the smallest distance
    for perm in list(itertools.permutations(permparm, len(permparm))):
        #Get the total weight of the permutation
        dist = getWeight(perm)
        #Make a new tour to represent the current permutation
        thisTour = [perm, dist]
        #If the current tour is shorter than the old tour, point the old tour to the new one
        if thisTour[1] < tour[1] and thisTour[1]<=int (maxweight):
            tour = thisTour
            return tour
    #Once we have gone through every permutation we have the shortest tour so return it
    return tour

#A function to get the total weight of a path
#This function is messy because of an off-by-1 error introduced by the tour file starting at 1 instead of 0
def getWeight(perm):
    #Set the initial distance to 0
    dist = 0
    #We now need to calculate and add the distance between each city in the path from 0 to n
    for index in range(len(perm)):
        try:
            #Pass the 2 cities to the distance formula and add the value to dist
            dist += getDistance(cities[perm[index]-1], cities[perm[index+1]-1])
        except:
            #We don't need to check bounds because the final pass will throw an out-of-bounds
            #exception so we just catch it and skip that calculation
            pass
    #All TSP solutions are cycles so we now have to add the final city back to the initial city to the total dist
    #Python has a nifty convention where list[-1] will return the last element, list[-2] will return second to last, etc.
    dist += getDistance(cities[perm[-1]-1], cities[perm[0]-1])
    #We now have the total distance so return it
    #if (int(dist)<=80.0):
    return dist

#A function to write the output of a tour to a file in a specified format
def toFile(tour):
    loc = input('Enter the location where you would like to save the tour:\n')
    fname = cityFile.name
    #Index for the last file separator to get ONLY the file name not its path
    sep_index = 0
    #Linux/OSX files use /'s to separate dirs so get the position of the last one in the name
    if '/' in fname:
        sep_index = fname.rindex('/')+1
    #Windows files use \'s to separate dirs so get the position of the last one in the name
    if '\\' in fname:
        sep_index = fname.rindex('\\')+1
    #Create the header for the output file
    header = ('NAME : ' + str(fname[sep_index:-4]) + '.opt.tour\n'
          'COMMENT : Optimal tour for ' + str(fname[sep_index:]) + ' (' + str(tour[1]) + ')\n'
          'TYPE : Tour\n'
          'DIMENSON : ' + str(len(tour[0])) + '\n'
          'TOUR_SECTION\n')
    #Create the trailer for the output file
    trailer = "-1\nEOF\n"
    #Create the output file and write the results to it
    try:
        f = open(loc,'w')
        f.write(header)
        for city in tour[0]:
            f.write(str(city) + '\n')
        f.write(trailer)
        f.close()
        print ('Successfully saved tour data to: ' + loc)
    except Exception as e:
        print (loc + ' could not be written to: ' + str(e))

#-------------------The actual script begins here-----------------------
cities = []
cityFile = getFile()
maxweight = find_max()
initfiles('in.txt')
#Start the stopwatch
start = time.time()
getCities(cityFile)
opt_tour = bruteForce(cities)
#Stop the stopwatch
finish = time.time()
print ('The optimum tour is: %s (%f)' % (opt_tour[0], opt_tour[1]))
print ('This solution took %0.3f seconds to calculate.' % (finish-start))
```

And my parallel code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import time, itertools, math
from multiprocessing import Pool,Manager


thisTour = None
tour = None
dist = None
totalct = 0

#Get the city file
def getFile():
    cityFile = 'in.txt'
    try:
        f = open(cityFile,'r')
        return f
    except Exception as e:
        print(cityFile + ' could not be opened: ' + str(e))

def find_max():
    file = open('in.txt','r')
    max = file.read().split()
    return max[1]

def initfiles(path):
    global totalct
    file = open(path, 'r')
    max = file.read().splitlines()
    totalct = len(max) - 2
    file.close()
    file = open(path, 'r')
    num = file.read().split()
    file.close()
    final = list()
    #print(totalct)
    final.append(str(num[0] + ' ' + num[1] + ' OK'))
    if (num[2] != 'OK'):


        file_write = open(path, 'wt')

        for i in range(1, int(num[0]) + 1):
            # print(max[i])
            final.append(str(i) + ' ' + str(max[i]))
            # print(i)
        # print(len(final))
        for line in range(len(final)):
            # print(final[line])
            file_write.write(str(final[line]) + '\n')

        print('File has been edited.')

        file_write.close()



#Get distance between 2 cities
#Cities stored as [ident, x, y]
def getDistance(city1, city2):
    return math.sqrt((int(city2[1]) - int(city1[1]))**2 + (int(city2[2])-int(city1[2]))**2)

#Get the cities from a specified city file
def getCities(cityFile):
    for line in cityFile:
        try:
            #Lines split by a space char will look like:
            #[ident, x-coord, y-coord]
            ident = line.split(' ')[0]
            x = line.split(' ')[1]
            y = line.split(' ')[2].strip('\n')
            #If the ident is not an int (not a city) skip it otherwise add it
            if ident.isdigit():
                #Cities are just lists with values (almost a pseudo-class)
                city = [int(ident), int(x), int(y)]
                cities.append(city)
        except:
            #The ident was not an int so we skip (pass) it and move on to the next
            pass

#A function for bruteforcing the TSP problem based on a list of cities
def bruteForce(perm):
    global maxweight
    global tour
    global thisTour

    dist = getWeight(perm)
    thisTour = [perm, dist]
    #If the current tour is shorter than the old tour, point the old tour to the new one
    if thisTour[1] < tour[1] and thisTour[1] <= int(maxweight):
        tour = thisTour
        return tour

    #Once we have gone through every permutation we have the shortest tour so return it
    return tour

#A function to get the total weight of a path
#This function is messy because of an off-by-1 error introduced by the tour file starting at 1 instead of 0
def getWeight(perm):
    #Set the initial distance to 0
    dist = 0
    #We now need to calculate and add the distance between each city in the path from 0 to n
    for index in range(len(perm)):
        try:
            #Pass the 2 cities to the distance formula and add the value to dist
            dist += getDistance(cities[perm[index]-1], cities[perm[index+1]-1])
        except:
            #We don't need to check bounds because the final pass will throw an out-of-bounds
            #exception so we just catch it and skip that calculation
            pass
    #All TSP solutions are cycles so we now have to add the final city back to the initial city to the total dist
    #Python has a nifty convention where list[-1] will return the last element, list[-2] will return second to last, etc.
    dist += getDistance(cities[perm[-1] - 1], cities[perm[0] - 1])
    #We now have the total distance so return it
    return dist

#A function to write the output of a tour to a file in a specified format
def toFile(tour):
    loc = input('Enter the location where you would like to save the tour:\n')
    fname = cityFile.name
    #Index for the last file separator to get ONLY the file name not its path
    sep_index = 0
    #Linux/OSX files use /'s to separate dirs so get the position of the last one in the name
    if '/' in fname:
        sep_index = fname.rindex('/')+1
    #Windows files use \'s to separate dirs so get the position of the last one in the name
    if '\\' in fname:
        sep_index = fname.rindex('\\')+1
    #Create the header for the output file
    header = ('NAME : ' + str(fname[sep_index:-4]) + '.opt.tour\n'
          'COMMENT : Optimal tour for ' + str(fname[sep_index:]) + ' (' + str(tour[1]) + ')\n'
          'TYPE : Tour\n'
          'DIMENSON : ' + str(len(tour[0])) + '\n'
          'TOUR_SECTION\n')
    #Create the trailer for the output file
    trailer = "-1\nEOF\n"
    #Create the output file and write the results to it
    try:
        f = open(loc,'w')
        f.write(header)
        for city in tour[0]:
            f.write(str(city) + '\n')
        f.write(trailer)
        f.close()
        print ('Successfully saved tour data to: ' + loc)
    except Exception as e:
        print (loc + ' could not be written to: ' + str(e))

#-------------------The actual script begins here-----------------------


def permutations():
    allperm = list(itertools.permutations(act, len(act)))
    for i in allperm:
        allpermlist.append(list(i))
    print('permutations compute has been finished.')
    return allpermlist

def allct ():
    for i in range(1, totalct):
        act.append(i)

def init():
    global thisTour
    global tour
    global dist

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cities = []
    cityFile = getFile()
    maxweight = find_max()
    initfiles('in.txt')
    manager = Manager()
    allpermlist = manager.list()
    tour = [[], float("inf")]
    allpermlist = []
    act = []
    allct()
    permutations()
    #Start the stopwatch
    start = time.time()
    getCities(cityFile)
    with Pool(processes=8, initializer=init) as p:
        opt_tour = p.map_async(bruteForce, allpermlist, chunksize=2048)
        opt_tour.wait()
    print(opt_tour.get())

    p.close()
    #p.join()
    finish = time.time()
    print('This solution took %0.3f seconds to calculate.' % (finish-start))
```

And my in.txt :

```
9 47 OK
1 13 15
2 4 21
3 7 17
4 8 11
5 10 14
6 2 15
7 14 11
8 15 20
9 13 17
```